# Cannot assign configuration entry 'tags' with value '"~@ignored"' of type java.lang.String to property of type java.util.List -> [Help 1]

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have a Automation test scripts which are running fine Jenkins Master but on slaves it is giving below error:

```
11:47:50 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.temyers:cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin:4.2.0:generateRunners (generateRunners) on project riverbed-automation-tests: Unable to parse configuration of mojo com.github.temyers:cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin:4.2.0:generateRunners for parameter tags: Cannot assign configuration entry 'tags' with value '"~@ignored"' of type java.lang.String to property of type java.util.List -> [Help 1]
11:47:50 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.temyers:cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin:4.2.0:generateRunners (generateRunners) on project riverbed-automation-tests: Unable to parse configuration of mojo com.github.temyers:cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin:4.2.0:generateRunners for parameter tags: Cannot assign configuration entry 'tags' with value '"~@ignored"' of type java.lang.String to property of type java.util.List
11:47:50    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:221)
11:47:50    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
11:47:50    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
11:47:50    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
11:47:50    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
11:47:50    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
11:47:50    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
11:47:50    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
11:47:50    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
11:47:50    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
11:47:50    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
11:47:50    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
11:47:50    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
11:47:50    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
11:47:50    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
11:47:50    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
11:47:50    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
11:47:50    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
11:47:50    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
11:47:50    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
```

this `Cucumber` `java` `junit` project with `Serenity`. Only difference between master and slave is that `Xvfb` (headless browser) is working on Master but not on Slave, but since it looks a Maven or Cucumber error I doubt `Xvfb` has anything to with it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should add some more specific tags to your post, "java" and "maven" is too broad. Moreover, I think you should post some more of your configuration files.

Comment: Done. What do you mean by configuration files? I gues, I don't have any.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Cucumber, anyway, the error message seems to say that you have set a "configuration entry 'tags' " in a wrong way.

Comment: Yeah, I am not even using this tag `~@ignored`. Its OK, appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin
There is stated:

> As of cucumber-jvm:4.0.0 parallel execution is supported natively by
>   cucumber. As such, upgrading to Cucumber 4.0.0 is recommended and this
>   plugin is no longer maintained.

So consider leave cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin

It looks like you have in your `pom.xml` something like

```
<tags>"~@ignore"</tags>
```

try to change it to

```
    <tags>
      <tag>~@ignore</tag>
    </tags>
```

BTW proper new style is now `not @ignore` check https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/tag-expressions#migrating-from-old-style-tags

Comment: I had it as `<tags>"~@ignore"</tags>` now I changed it to what you suggested but still same problem. I didnt get the `not @ignore` how to write it in pom, is it like `<tags>
          <tag>not @ignore</tag>
         </tags> `??

Comment: Probably easiest for you is to delete whole `<tags>...</tags>` section. This ~@ignore just tell cucumber to run all scenarios which are NOT marked as ignore. You can specify this in command line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is maven version

Following format for list/set is support in maven `3.3.9` and onward versions but in lower versions it not supported.

```
<tags>val1,val2,val3...</tags>
```

But in maven version less than `3.3.9`, above is not supported

To fix make it backward compatible

```
<tags>
    <tag>val1</tag>
    <tag>val2</tag>
    .....
</tags>
```

PS: for more details check [this](https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin/issues/441#issuecomment-283054098) link